# How to get a line chart inside a circle using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have to do a few charts using D3. First, a pie chart and then a line chart inside the pie hole. I know how to do a line chart right now, and translate that to the center of the pie chart but the problem is how the line chart is filled. **How can I get the line chart filled but with a curved form?**

**What I have to do**:

[image: Design]

**What I have done**:

[image: What I have so far]

The code I have to get a line chart:

```
var months = [
    {month: 1, amount: 120000},
    ...
];
var calculateX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, this.width])
            .domain(d3.extent(months, (d) => d.month * 10));
var calculateY = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, (this.height / 2) - 20])
            .domain([d3.min(months, (d) => d.amount), d3.max(months, (d) => d.amount)]);


    var lines = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return calculateX(d.month * 10);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return calculateY(d.amount);
        })
        .curve(d3.curveBasis);

    lineGraph.datum(this.months);

    lineGraph.append('path')
        .attr('class', 'median-line')
        .attr('d', lines)
        .style("stroke", '#DAF2CD')
        .style("fill", '#D0ECB8');
```

Comment: Use a clipPath: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Comment: Or a mask https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#masking-Masking

Comment: Thank you. I used clipPath!